# A feed in which different users can add activities

Tags: getstream-io

In my app I want to have some feed where different users can add activities

How can I do this? Are there any settings of user rights?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could elaborate on what you are trying to build (e.g. what kind of user ACL you are trying to offload to Stream) and whether you are using an SDK or the REST API directly. Multiple users can add activities to the same feed.
Regarding user rights, permissions they would be embedded in the JWT token when you're doing server-side authentication, as exposed [here](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#serverside_authentication).