# getStream - Flat Feed where multiple users can post

Tags: ruby, reactjs, getstream-io

we are implementing stream in our application and so far we love the out of the box [react components](https://github.com/GetStream/react-activity-feed) as well as the backend implementation [stream ruby](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-ruby) - this is our setup currently.

We are close to deploying a first MVP but found that it seems to be not possible to post activities to a flat feed from multiple users by default.

Our use case is that we have a group of people that want to post activities about a certain topic (think facebook groups). Therefore we create a feed for the object (lets say a company) and want each user to be able to post activities there. Our current workaround is to add the author id as additional data and add a custom header to a activity - obviously not the best solution as reactions won't work that way.

Looking around we found that this seems to not work out of the box see [this issue](https://github.com/GetStream/react-activity-feed/issues/23) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487890/a-feed-in-which-different-users-can-add-activities).

Is this a feature that is only available to paying customers or how can we activate it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Stream with React users can only post to their own user feed, this is a default permission policy that can be changed by Stream.

I suggest reaching to Stream support by email and ask to change the permission policy.

Comment: Thank for your Answer! So in the free plan stream does not seem to give email support - only through stackoverflow.

This is why I asked the question here, but I guess I can try to contact their sales department to inquire about that.

Anyway good to know that there is no way to do that without support.